# Is a world known CA certificate compulsory for a https site?

Tags: https, openssl, certificate, tls1.2, keytool

I want my site to be secure using HTTPS protocols. I managed to make a self-signed key to be `trustedCertEntry` as I made my own CA certificate, with different CN, which I used to sign my own private certificate.
It works smooth testing it with openssl with something like:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.mydomain.com:80 -tls1 -state
```

Thus, browser doesn't report a `certificate self-signed` error, as it sees a different CA.

But I get a `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` error. Still it seems logical to me as nobody knows me as a CA. It is supposed to work if user adds exception for me.
I thought this trick was acceptable and it was like many https compliant sites were working, as you may visit a unknown site and you want to encrypt communications from 3rd party watchers but trust that page.
After trying to get a clear response for it, beyond coding that I will find resources, my question is:

If I want to have a site, for which the users don't have to add an exception in the first visit, do I have to get a certificate from a "world-known" CA? Or am I missing a solution for self-signing my certificate with my own CA certificate?

Comment: Yes, you will have to get a certificate from a CA that is trusted by your users' browsers via a chain of intermediary CA's that ends at an inherently trusted root CA. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity)

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a clear response. Tutorials about self CA certificate don't (what I have seen, at least) point clearly that is useless for webs expecting unknown visitors, happily assuming everybody will trust and install your certificate previously.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer and i'll check it?

Comment: OK, I posted an answer and provided an alternative approach that might work for you (assuming that you were mostly worried about cost and effort :-) )

Comment: Not only gave me the response, but also made me learn me a lot. Thank you very much, Reinier! ;-)

Comment: I'm using Let's Encrypt, it fits perfectly for my case right now. Will see when I need other certificate features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the answer is: Yes, you will have to get a certificate from a CA that is trusted by your users' browsers via a chain of intermediary CA's that ends at an inherently trusted root CA. The accepted answer to this question explains how it works: [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56389)

Having said that, if your "only" concern is to provide encrypted connections, you might be able to leverage the [Let's Encrypt CA](https://letsencrypt.org), which provides free certificates for that purpose. Those certificates will be only [domain-validated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-validated_certificate), which provides a weaker kind of assurance of identity than, for example, an [Extended Validation Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).

Depending on the browser used, there will be minimal difference in user experience between DV and EV certificates. For Safari, the user will see a grey padlock in the address bar for the lower assurance DV-backed sites, like this:

[image: Grey padlock]

and a green padlock when higher identity assurance is provided, like this:

[image]

Whether the former is good enough for you (or your customers) depends on your situation.

In case you want to understand what "inherently trusted" actually means for web browsers, see this blog post: [Who your browser trusts, and how to control it.](https://certsimple.com/blog/control-the-ssl-cas-your-browser-trusts)